# How come it is not undefined if vfork( ) calls exec family?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

According to `vfork()` man page, the behaviour is undefined if `vfork()` modifies any data, other than pid_t **before it calls either _exit or exec family of syscalls.**

By this I understand, that if the child process created by `vfork()` calls `exec()`, then it can modify any data, and the behaviour is still not undefined.

My questions are:

1. It is also known that child shares parent address space, so how come if child overwrites, self and parent image using exec, the behaviour is not undefined?
2. What happens to parent, if the child calls exec and after that it returns? Does the parent start using the new copy, created by child using exec?

Comment: Personally, I assume `vfork()` does not exist and never use it.  Ditto for `gets()`.  It is simpler than anguishing over whether a platform supports it and how it supports it.

Comment: It exists, but it's behavious contradicts as in man page :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your key misunderstanding is what `exec` does: it does not "overwrite memory" with the new process. Rather it throws away its entire virtual memory (whether it was previously private mappings, shared mappings, or whatever) and creates a completely new virtual address space for the calling process id corresponding to the new process image (executable). This has no bearing on the parent's address space except that the reference count on the memory management structures is decremented (it was incremented by `vfork`).

Comment: :I am confused, as because one hand it says vfork( ) child shares address with parent, then how come exec does not destroy parent copy, except until child does copy-on-write on exec, right?

Comment: So by your point, i think there is a copy-on-write on exec, right?

Comment: No, you're just mistaken about how virtual memory works. `exec` always makes a new virtual address space, initially populated just with mappings of the new binary, the dynamic linker, and a stack. It doesn't write to anything.

Comment: Thanks i will accept your answer as it is more close to my expectations. You said :`always makes a new virtual address space, initially populated just with mappings of the new binary, the dynamic linker, and a stack` can you please give me a link which states the details of exec on vfork so that it can further clear my concepts?

Comment: Since the "how" of `vfork` is not specified anywhere and indeed any nontrivial use of `vfork` is just specified as **undefined behavior**, I think you'd do better to read some source code. The `exec` source for Linux (or for one of the BSDs, which tend to be simpler/clearer) would be a great starting point.

Comment: BTW I mean kernel source, not userspace library source which will just be a syscall.

Answer (score 5):

The `exec` call replaces the child's entire address space with a whole new address space. Any shared address space would be replaced completely by the call.

The `vfork` function exists only as an optimization. For some operating systems, `fork` is very expensive because the child process could potentially modify any page mapped into memory, so every single page must be modified to copy on write (or, originally, actually copied!) so as not to modify the parent's corresponding pages. A very common sequence is `fork` followed immediately by `exec`, forcing these systems to remap all the pages just to throw them all away a split second later. Rather than going to the trouble of modifying all the mappings, `vfork` allows you to leave the mappings in an undefined state in the child process under the assumption that you're not going to use them anyway.

As a result, doing certain things after a `vfork` can create a mess. But as soon as you call `exec`, all the undefined mappings are gone anyway.

In practice, operating systems handle `vfork` one of two ways: For operating systems where changing all mappings to copy on write is inexpensive or that haven't implemented `vfork` optimization, `vfork` is identical to `fork`. For operating systems that do use `vfork` optimization, `vfork` leaves the parent and child fully sharing most pages, causing bad things to happen if the child modifies them (they modify in the parent).

So the short answer to your question is that if `vfork` was designed that way, it wouldn't be usable for its sole intended purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still one doubt remains (same as i asked Omnifarious) See my comment on Zack, don't you think ls -l should have been executed twice? Once from child, and another time from parent, after it resumes execution? It actually does not, but why? It will be great if i know your opinion too.

Comment: I think your answer is a bit better and more coherent than mine.

Answer (score 4):

`vfork` may not actually share the address space. It is specifically undefined whether or not it does so. This is because duplicating the address space has become very cheap on modern operating systems so having to implement a call that doesn't may be more trouble than it's worth.

Also, if `vfork` does share address space, it will be sharing the stack. Having one process pop items off a shared stack unbeknownst to the other is a very bad idea.

`exec` creates a brand new address space for the process and 'forgets' the old one. Since in a `vfork` situation there may (or may not) be two processes using that address space, a reference count on it will be decremented and the parent process will be able to continue using the address space just fine.

A child process cannot 'return' from a successful `exec`. After a successful `exec` a new address space is created and execution begins in the process starting at `main`.

`vfork` does potentially have the effect of pausing the parent until the child executes `exec` or `exit`. In this sense a child can sort of return from `exec` because the execution of the parent process will them resume if it has been halted. But the address space of the parent process is left untouched even in the shared situation because either the `exec` or the `exit` case will result in simply one less reference to the original (the parent's) address space.

Comment: Can you please answer my second question? Suppose let us assume ideal case (it is shared), then what happens if child calls exec? Does the parent on resuming start using the new image?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - I believe my edited response now also answers your second question.

Comment: See my comment on Zack, don't you think `ls -l` should have been executed twice? Once from child, and another time from parent, after it resumes execution? It actually does not, but why?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your question, but when the child calls 'exec' its address space no longer exists. This has no effect on the parent at all. Think of it like closing a handle -- it simply disassociates the child process from the address space it shared with the parent.

Comment: @David Schwartz: Then how come the printf on parent after a exec on child, does not work?

Comment: @David Schwartz: I just re-executed my program, with 3 printf in parent. Starngely the parent executed first. Then the child, where expected is, after vfork the parent should be immediately suspended.

Comment: Remember, 'vfork' is specifically intended to have weakly-defined semantics. The idea is to leave the operating system free to do things in the way that's most efficient on that operating system. If running the parent first is more efficient, the OS is free to do it that way. If sharing the pages adds no efficiency on that OS, the OS is not required to do that.

Comment: `But the address space of the parent process is left untouched even in the shared situation because either the exec or the exit` is correct as my program proves. I accept your answer as it explains elaborately.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the basic point of confusion: Normally, `fork` creates a new address space by duplicating the parent, and `exec` replaces the caller's address space with a fresh one loaded from an executable on disk.  So, if `vfork` *doesn't* duplicate the parent address space, how is it that calling `exec` after `vfork` doesn't destroy the parent address space, leaving the parent with nowhere to resume execution?

The answer is that that would make `vfork` useless, so the kernel avoids it.  When `exec` is called from the child side of a `vfork`, it creates a new address space, loads the executable *there*, and leaves the calling address space alone.  The child process is then context-switched to the new address space, and the parent process resumes execution in its unmodified original address space.

All of the danger of `vfork` stems from the child *temporarily* executing in the parent's address space until it calls `exec` or `_exit`.  Any side effects of what the child does in there stick, and affect the parent, possibly catastrophically.  Unless you're on a system where `vfork` is just an alias for `fork`, in which case they don't stick.  Thus you can't count on either behavior and you have to avoid doing anything in the child.

Answer (score 1):

`vfork` was *invented* as an optimization for `fork` + `exec`. The whole idea was, 'if your plan is to call `fork()` and then `exec(...)`', use `vfork` and we'll do whatever we can to take advantage of that and speed things up.'

The restriction is to allow implementors the maximum flexibility, including arbitrary surprises if you do anything other than exec.

A child can't 'call exec and then return'. The exec family *does not return*. It replaces the entire image. So the second part of your question isn't answerable.

Comment: `A child can't 'call exec and then return'. The exec family does not return. It replaces the entire image.` So it means, in case of exec, there is no concept of waking up the parent from suspended state?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: No, the parent wakes up in its original address space; `exec` does *not* destroy the calling address space when called from the child side of a `vfork`.  See my answer.

Comment: What does 'returning' have to do with 'waking the parent'? Again, it seems like you are trying to extract a contract from the internal workings of vfork, when the whole point is that the implementors are free to play 'pop goes the weasel' on your audio if you do anything except turn around and call exec in the child.

Answer (score 1):

vfork MIGHT not actually run the forked process in a separate address-space, so it behaves more like a "thread" (except without concurrent execution or a separate stack). This means that you have to do, well, nothing in the child except exec or _exit.

Some kernels (uclinux? ELKS?) which support vfork do not support fork - for example, on MMU-less systems, supporting fork() is essentially impossible (even by copying pages). Each process needs to be started independently, as they all share address-space.

So vfork can be correctly implemented on these, but fork can't.